# Spring Criteria API - One to Many n Children's missing where clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am amidst implementations for Having Spring Criteria API (Specification) with paging & sorting

Since we have one to many relations where parent is one (not n child) I am querying over Parent
The where clause when fetching parent(with joins) works fine

However when lazy loaded children are loaded on the miss the where clause.

```
public class ASpecification implements Specification<A> {
...
 @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<A> root,
                                 CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery,
                                 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicate = new ArrayList<>();
        ListJoin<A, B> aBListJoin = root.join(b, JoinType.LEFT);
        ListJoin<A, C> aCListJoin = root.join(c, JoinType.LEFT);

        // we know below wont work because MultipleBagFetchException
        // ListJoin<A, B> aBListJoin = root.fetch(b, JoinType.LEFT); 
        // ListJoin<A, C> aCListJoin = root.fetch(c, JoinType.LEFT);

       // also thinking of below but not sure if it will do the trick 
       // because to my best understanding it wont work with findAll
       
       /*criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(ItemInventory_.NAME),
                root.get(ItemInventory_.fullName),
                root.get(ItemInventory_.parentRefFullName),
                itemInventoryItemStockListJoin,
                itemInventoryBinLocationListJoin);*/
........

}
```

Join Column below is ideal but missing child select query

```
Hibernate: 
    /* <criteria> */ select
        i1_0.Id,... /*only A columns generated here :(*/ 
    from
        A i1_0 
    left join
        B i2_0 
            on i1_0.foo=i2_0.bar 
    left join
        Binlocation b1_0 
            on i1_0.foo=b1_0.tai
    where
        i1_0.IsActive=? 
        and i2_0.location=? 
        and b1_0.location=? 
    order by
        (select
            0) offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

Child query below

```
select
        i1_0.id //... other columns
    from
        B i1_0 
    where
        i1_0.bar=?
    // but missing location where clause :(
```

Lastly If the impl is not recommended
I am planning to to use

```
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

which should hopefully give me more control
instead of

```
aRepo.findAll(specification, pageable);
```

But was hoping to avoid it...